# Calling different version of Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver with Ruby. I have two versions of Ruby installed *(Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0). I have been getting this error:

```
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'.
```

I am thinking if I somehow call Ruby version 1.9.3 in my scripts this error can be avoided. Can someone tell me how to do that? Will this solve the issue?

Comment: Please post some of your code.

Comment: Also, I would recommend https://rvm.io/ if you want to easily be able to switch between ruby versions.

Comment: With windows I use uru

Comment: To add to @AMACB, there are other similar tools. [rbenv](github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) come to mind. Disclaimer, I use rvm

Comment: It depends on how you installed the two versions of ruby. You normally use a [ruby version manager](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/ruby_version_management)

Comment: 'bundle install' while you are using 2.0?

Comment: Oh by the way I am on Windows

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Can someone share the link to download ans steps in install uru ( I am using Windows 7). I tried downloading and saving it to my tools folder in C:/ but when I enter "uru_rt admin install" in command line it says "uru is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: The uru script must be in a folder in your path (or you are in the uru folder)